# What is friend function in php?

Tags: c#, php

Now I am heard about friend function in c# then I am just google it for know about it. I am wondered that in php is also allow friend function. So my question is that what is friend function ? How can I use it in php? Is this use only in OOPs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concepts of encapsulation and abstraction (data hiding) indicate that non-member functions should not be able to access an object’s private and protected data. The policy is that if you are not a member, you can’t get in. But certain situations may arise wherein you need to share your private or protected data with non-members. Here, ‘Friends’ come to the rescue.

A friend function is a non-member function that has access to a class’s private and protected members.

Pointers for friend functions:

A friend function may be declared a 'friend' to more than one class.
It does not have the class' scope as it depends on function’s original definition and declaration.
It does not require an object (of the class that declares it a friend). It can be invoked like a normal function.
Since it is not a member function, it cannot access the members of the class directly and has to use an object name and membership operator (.) with each member name.
It can be declared anywhere in the class without affecting its meaning.
A member function of the class operates upon the members of the object used to invoke it, whereas a friend function operates upon the object passed to it as an argument.[Link for php](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34044)

**PHP implementation**

```
class MyBaseClass  
{  
    protected static $friendClasses = array();  

    public function __get($name)  
    {  
        if (  
            // check if the caller's class is one of the friend classes  
            ($trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)) &&  
             (isset($trace[1]['class']) && in_array($trace[1]['class'], static::$friendClasses))  
        ) {  
            return $this->$name;  
        } else {  
            trigger_error('Member not available: ' . $name, E_USER_ERROR);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

[Link reference](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/n618/news/view/49401/14863/friend-classes-in-php.html)

Answer (score 2):

Friend function is best shared among a number of different classes. Such functions can be declared either as member functions of one class or as global functions. In either case they can be set to be friends of other classes, by using a friend specifier in the class that is admitting them. Such functions can use all attributes of the class which names them as a friend, as if they were themselves members of that class.

A friend declaration is essentially a prototype for a member function, but instead of requiring an implementation with the name of that class attached by the double colon syntax, a global function or member function of another class provides the match.

For this PHP 5.3+ implementation you will need a base class. A class that should be extended by the classes that need to have friends. This base class provides the friend-architecture, so that it will need to be coded only once.

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    protected static $friendClasses = array();

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (
            // check if the caller's class is one of the friend classes
            ($trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS)) &&
             (isset($trace[1]['class']) && in_array($trace[1]['class'], static::$friendClasses))
        ) {
            return $this->$name;
        } else {
            trigger_error('Member not available: ' . $name, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}

Then all you need to do do make add a friend to your class is declare it.

class Pooh extends MyBaseClass
{
    protected static $friendClasses = array('Piglet', 'Tigger');

    protected $feelings = 'sad';
}

class Piglet
{
    public function beSensitive(MyBaseClass $Character)
    {
        echo 'You are so ' . $Character->feelings . '!';
    }
}
```

Now a Piglet can access a Pooh's feelings.

```
$Pooh = new Pooh();
$Piglet = new Piglet();
$Piglet->beSensitive($Pooh);
```

Friend functions allow binary operators to be defined which combine private data in a pair of objects. This is particularly powerful when using the operator overloading features of C++. We will return to it when we look at overloading.

Comment: So what is the difference in friend function in php and c#